# ColdFusion error: "Element REMOTEADDRESS is undefined in ERROR." How do I fix it?

Tags: coldfusion

I have a custom ColdFusion error page that is repeatedly returning the following error, often after the page has been scanned by a bot:

Element REMOTEADDRESS is undefined in ERROR. 
The error occurred on ### (page number).

I'm not sure why it is returning this undefined element error, or if there is a way to get around it, other than removing the #error.remoteAddress# code.

My code looks like this:

```
<cferror type="REQUEST" template="error.cfm" mailto="email@domain.com">
<cfoutput>
 <ul>
  <li><strong>Your Location:</strong> #error.remoteAddress#
  <li><strong>Your Browser:</strong> #error.browser#
  <li><strong>Date and Time the Error Occurred:</strong> #error.dateTime#
  <li><strong>Page You Came From:</strong> #error.HTTPReferer#
  <li><strong>Error Diagnostics</strong>:
  <p>#error.diagnostics#</p>
 </ul>
</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without fully understanding the overall logic here, if you want to be able to safely test to see if a variable, or structure's member exists before trying to evaluate it, you can do something like

```
<cfif isDefined("error") AND structKeyExists(error, "remoteAddress")>#error.remoteAddress#</cfif>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should either use Edward's solution to verify the existence of the variable, or cfparam the value so that it always exists:

```
<cfparam name="Error.remoteAddress" default="No Remote Address" />
```

Answer (score 2):

remoteAddress is only available in [request and exception type errors](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d29.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d29__WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec17cba-7fa4), so check the error type before displaying an error variable.

```
<cfif ListFind("request,exception",error.type)>
   <li><strong>Your Location:</strong> #error.remoteAddress#</li>
</cfif>
```

You could also check that the error type isn't "validation", but I like to be a positive kind of guy.

ps. notice I closed your list item. ;)